# password length with pam_cracklib.so

Tags: linux, password, pam

I ran a security scan in a RedHat Linux Server and got the following vulnerabilty:

> Incorrect System Default minimum password length or password complexity rules. Minimum
>   password length should be set to 8. It should be set through pam_cracklib.so or
>   pam_pwquality.so or pam_passwdqc.so.

in the /etc/pam.d/system-auth I set the following line:

```
password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=5  minlength=8
```

but somehow I am still getting the same vulnerability. I don’t  know which parameter am I missing in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page for `pam_cracklib`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_cracklib.8.html) lists the options the module accepts. Among them is what you're probably looking for:

> `minlen=N`
>      The minimum acceptable size for the new password

Note the abbreviated spelling, it's `minlen`, not `minlength`. The module might or might not log an error message for `minlength` if it doesn't recognize it. (One might be tempted to say that the module should fail if it's given an unknown option.)

Note that `minlength` isn't exact, `pam_cracklib` gives so called "credit" for the password having e.g. upper case letters and digits. Check the documentation for `ucredit`, `lcredit`, `ocredit` and `dcredit` carefully.

Also, it's probably a good idea to test the actual behaviour after configuring stuff like that.